# Best place to put pricing table

Tags: website-design, scenarios

I have a pricing table, something like this:

[image]

**Scenario #1: *Home Page***

Actually I'm using one page layout for website, something like this:

http://www.apple.com/iphone/features/

and here is an option to put pricing table at the end of the page. Readers after reaching at the end of the page (actually by scrolling it and read all awesome features of our service) start to choose their desired plan and after that they redirects to registration wizard page, and start to complete their registration fields.

> *"hey, wait! I forgot what plan I choose in previous page."* -The User

So, In the first step of the wizard I must put this pricing table again and highlight the plan he choose in home page.

After completing it, the confirmation email sent to their inbox. And then after confirming their email address they will asked for paying the invoice via paypal or any other banking services out there.

> *"come on! Its 20.99$. No way ! I wanna change my plan to 5.99$."* -The User

So, There is also an option in that page that let the user to change his/her decision and choose another plan. And ***"again"*** I must put this pricing table to that page, to let the user to change its decision for third time !

**Scenario #2: *In payment time***

There is also another option to put a beautiful *register now!* image at the end of my one page layout, and then by clicking the image it will redirects user to registration wizard page. And then completing the registration fields and then confirm email address and then he will asked for choosing the desired plan.

> just choose and pay !

**Scenario #3: *Pay when needed***

After registration, *The User* will start using the software, and when he clicks any links on the user's dashboard page he will asked for payment and then the pricing table will shown for him/her.

What do you think about these scenarios ? Which one is better for a web service ?
Any other scenario would be most welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question. Since you are using a single page layout for your website, I would focus on two things :

- **Dont overwhelm the user with all the choices at front by presenting the table upfront when he lands on your page**. This is because users might get turned off by the price and decide to go somewhere and you would have already lost a customer. I would recommend using an initial teaser which might be "Plans as low as $ 5.99" which is then hyperlinked to the anchor on your page where the plans are displayed. Some examples are given below:

[image]

[image]

- **Ensure users are always informed of what plan they have chosen even during the registration page or payment page** : This will prevent any surprises and keep them informed about what plan they opted for. If you also have the screen space, I also recommend highlighting some key features of the plan below the pricing

I do like **scenario #2** as it would drive the user to actually signing up for an account but if you can make your call to action button more enticing and helpful such as these examples below :

[image]

[image]

[image]

The above examples just dont tell you to sign up but also let you know what is the potential lowest plan you can choose or if there is a free trial.

I **dont like scenario #3** since If I find I have to sign up for a plan and fork out some money to start using your software(after I finished downloading and installing it), I am going to get very annoyed.
Here are some good articles about best practices about pricing tables

[Pricing Tables: Examples And Best Practices](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/10/13/pricing-tables-showcase-examples-and-best-practices/)

[Examples and Best Practice for Creating Effective Pricing Tables](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2010/08/examples-and-best-practice-for-creating-effective-pricing-tables.html)

[Pricing Tables – Best Practices, Tips and Inspiration](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/inspiration/pricing-tables-tips-tricks/)

Comment: Its a long time you just answer this question, so many thanks for the great answer. It helped me a lot.